# user_posts not available in Facebook GraphAPI Explorer

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

Currently using the Graph API Explorer to get `posts`, but even with the access token of an admin role, the `user_posts` permissions does not appear in the drop down list.

[image: permission not appearing]

Clearly, trying to get `posts` without the permission results in an error.

[image: debug error without the permission]

Other (non-approved) permissions such as `user_photos` and `user_likes` are appearing with no issue. `user_posts` is still appearing in the Facebook login documentation as well, and I haven't seen any reference of it being deprecated in the change logs or breaking changes.

Anyone knows if this is a bug or intentional?

**Edit:** Also no luck using the Access Token Tool in the classic Graph API Explorer, shown below.

[image: Classic view]

Comment: Where exactly in GAE do you find this dropdown? Never seen it before.

Comment: @Cbroe It's in the new (beta) Graph API Explorer. Sadly `user_posts` is also missing in the classic view.

Comment: Is your app in dev or live mode?

Comment: @CBroe Live mode.

Comment: Then try dev mode.